# Java Servlet Not Redirecting

Tags: java, servlets

I believe my code should redirect to the "Login" servlet. It currently isn't using any validation so in reality it really should just re-direct me to the other servlet once ran. I am not getting on 404 errors or 500 level errors it just keep redirecting me to my Register servlet and not Login

```
@WebServlet("/Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // Create an array list of guest book HW1Users
        ArrayList<HW1User> HW1Users = new ArrayList<HW1User>();
        // Add the array list to the application scope
        getServletContext().setAttribute("HW1Users", HW1Users);     
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<meta charset=\"ISO-8859-1\">");
        out.println("<title>Israel, Dylan - CS320stu32</title>");
        out.println(
                "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css\">");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<form class=\"form-horizontal\">");

        out.println("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        out.println("<label for=\"name\" class=\"col-sm-2 control-label\">Name:</label>");
        out.println("<div class=\"col-sm-10\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"name\" placeholder=\"First and Last Name\">");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</div>");

        out.println("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        out.println("<label for=\"inputEmail3\" class=\"col-sm-2 control-label\">Email:</label>");
        out.println("<div class=\"col-sm-10\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputEmail3\" placeholder=\"Enter Email\">");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</div>");

        out.println("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        out.println("<label for=\"password1\" class=\"col-sm-2 control-label\">Password:</label>");
        out.println("<div class=\"col-sm-10\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"password1\" placeholder=\"Enter Password\">");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</div>");

        out.println("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        out.println("<label for=\"password2\" class=\"col-sm-2 control-label\">Re-Enter Password:</label>");
        out.println("<div class=\"col-sm-10\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"password2\" placeholder=\"Re-Enter Password\">");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</div>");

        out.println("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        out.println("<div class=\"col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value = \"Register\"/>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</form>");
        // Grab a reference to the list of HW1Users
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String password1 = request.getParameter("password1");
        String password2 = request.getParameter("password2");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");

        ArrayList<HW1User> HW1Users = (ArrayList<HW1User>)getServletContext().getAttribute("HW1Users");

        HW1Users.add(new HW1User(name,password1,password2,email));
        // Add the new entry to the list

        if(HW1Users!= null){

        response.sendRedirect("/Login");
        }
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

After Kumar's answer I've updated my code to:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String password1 = request.getParameter("password1");
    String password2 = request.getParameter("password2");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    ArrayList<HW1User> HW1Users = (ArrayList<HW1User>)getServletContext().getAttribute("HW1Users");

    HW1Users.add(new HW1User(name,password1,password2,email));
    // Add the new entry to the list

    if(HW1Users!= null){

    response.sendRedirect("/Login");
    return; // returns causing response stream to be committed only once
    }
    doGet(request, response); // This will treat your request as a get request only if HW1Users is null
}
```

Here is my Login Servlet code to show that it isn't re-directing to anything.

```
                     @WebServlet("/Login")
     public class Login extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("   <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
    out.println("   <title>Sessions Login</title>");
    out.println("   <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css\">");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<div class=\"container\">");

    String error = (String) request.getAttribute("error");
    if (error != null)
        out.println("<p class=\"text-danger lead\">" + error + "</p>");

    // Page-Specific Content
    out.println("<form action=\"Login\" method=\"post\" >");
    out.println("   Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" /> <br />");
    out.println("   Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" /> <br />");
    out.println("   <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\" />");

    out.println("</form>");

    out.println("</div>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>    ");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if (username != null && username.equals("albert") 
            && password != null && password.equals("1!") ){

        // Create a Session Variable named Username
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", "Albert F. Cervantes");

        // Redirect to the Member's Only page
        response.sendRedirect("Members");
    }
    else {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid Username and/or Password");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: As I currently observe,your response will get committed twice with response.redirect and doGet.Consider adding a return statement after reponse.sendRedirect

Comment: @KumarAbhinav Add a return statement to do what exactly. I apologize if it seems like a silly question.

Comment: The second problem you have now is using an absolute path for redirect: `"/Login"`. Check the url after POSTing to this servlet. Try removing the `"/"`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have tried removing the / from Login, but the result remains the same. It continues to return me to Register.

Comment: Have you properly debugged to check if (oddly enough) is executing the redirect? What's the code of your Login servlet? Are you sure Login servlet does not redirect back to Register?

Comment: @DylanC.Israel Please post the servlet code for Login

Comment: @KumarAbhinav  the login servlet code is up now as well.

Comment: @DylanC.Israel what address do you see in address bar of browser?Try adding the output screenshot.Also ,let me tell you that adding pure html in servlet code is not a good practice.Try creating a jsp  and using a request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: @KumarAbhinav What do you mean by output screenshot? As for JSP this is coursework I'm working on and must follow a certain criteria and JSP isn't included in that sadly. Also, the url I'm getting is localhost:8000/cs320/Register

Answer (score 2):

Your response will get committed twice with `response.sendRedirect("/Login");` and  `doGet(request, response);`.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String password1 = request.getParameter("password1");
        String password2 = request.getParameter("password2");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");

        ArrayList<HW1User> HW1Users = (ArrayList<HW1User>)getServletContext().getAttribute("HW1Users");

        HW1Users.add(new HW1User(name,password1,password2,email));
        // Add the new entry to the list

        if(HW1Users!= null){    
        response.sendRedirect("/Login");
        return; // returns causing response stream to be committed only once
        }
        doGet(request, response); // This will treat your request as a get request only if HW1Users is null 
    }
```

Comment: I see what your saying. I tried this option and am still not getting it to redirect unfortunately.

Comment: @DylanC.Israel What you are getting? an error 404 or error 500.Try adding a snapshot for a complete verifiable  and reproducible code

Comment: I edited my current code to to show the edited version. I also am not getting an 404 or 500 errors. It just keeps sending me back to my Register Servlet and not Login.